# Vim's dbext with postgres

Tags: vimrc

Has anyone successfully configured a postgres database in vim's dbext ?

I see only configurations for mysql or sqllite.

I included the following code in .vimrc:

```
 let g:dbext_default_profile_mydb='type=pgsql:user=mydb:mydb=localhost:dsnname=mydb:dbname=mydb'
 let g:dbext_default_profile='mydb'
```

mydb is the database, role, username and password for my database.

when I list connections I got this error:

```
dbext:Unknown parameter: POSTGRESQL_bin
dbext:Unknown parameter: POSTGRESQL_cmd_header
dbext:Unknown parameter: POSTGRESQL_cmd_terminator
dbext:Unknown parameter: POSTGRESQL_cmd_options
dbext:Unknown parameter: POSTGRESQL_on_error
dbext:Unknown parameter: utilities
dbext:Unknown parameter: POSTGRESQL_cmd_terminator
dbext:A valid database type must be chosen
```

can anyone show me the correct line to put in .vimrc for accessing a postgresql database with dbext please ?

if I use DBPromptForBufferParameters command it works ok.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct configuration for using postgres with dbext. Put these lines in your .vim

```
 let g:dbext_default_profile_myDB='type=pgsql:host=localhost:user=myUser:dsnname=myDB:dbname=myDB:passwd=myPassword'
 let g:dbext_default_profile='myDB'
```